# How do I access array elements using int value going from IDL to python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, indexing, idl

I am working on code conversion from IDL to python and came across a hurdle. Some code I was given needs to be converted to python. In the IDL version, array element is accessed by int value rather than 3D index. Using the same technique, python gives an error. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Here is a snippet of IDL code for illustration purposes:

```
x = reform(indgen(100), 2, 5, 10)
help, x ;this results in Array[2,5,10]
x[-76] ; results in value 24
```

Here is a snippet of python code for illustration purposes

```
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(100).reshape(2,5,10)
x.shape #this results in (2,5,10)
x[-76]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index -76 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Comment: Your question is not just about Python, but numpy specifically. Python nor numpy automatically 'flatten' the index into a numpy array like you describe, although it's clear how that would work. You could inherit from a numpy array and add logic that would do this, but this would only work on array you define yourself (of that type), you can't change how a numpy array works inherently. A better solution might be to write a simple function that you call to index this way i.e. `flat(x, 0-76)` (or `flat(x)[-76]`  if you need to return something that takes otherwise similar indices)

Comment: I believe that would be `x[0][2][4]`

Comment: @charanjitpabla John Gordon assumes you are merely asking how to index a multi-dimensional array, I assumed you wanted to add a way to index such arrays, can you clarify what you meant and in what cases you need this to work?

Comment: I want this to work for other indices as well. The x[0][2][4] works but what if I say x[-33]? How do I get the 3-dimensional indices for any given 1D index. IDL has array_indices.pro [ https://www.nv5geospatialsoftware.com/docs/ARRAY_INDICES.html ]  function but does python has something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy arrays (or anything indexed with integers in Python) doesn't just support that flattened type of indexing. For one, it assumes we know in what order the dimensions are kept in memory, which can be risky.

However, NumPy does include some functions and methods to help with this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100).reshape(2, 5, 10)

# to just get the value at that IDL index
print(x.flat[-76])


def idl_idx(xs: np.ndarray, idx: int):
    # unravel_index doesn't support negative indices, so convert them
    if idx < 0:
        idx = xs.size + idx
    return np.unravel_index(idx, xs.shape)


# to get the index as a tuple
print(idl_idx(x, -76))

# to just get that value normally
print(x[0, 2, 4])
```

Output:

```
24
(0, 2, 4)
24
```

There's no way to change the `np.ndarray` type itself to support this behaviour, although you could subclass it and add this behaviour. But that would have the limitation of only working for arrays of that type, while some functions (in NumPy and elsewhere) may return new arrays of type `np.ndarray` that would no longer work like that - that may be something you want to avoid.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Is x.flat[] sensitive to dimension order? Reason I ask is IDL and python arrays are different when it comes to column, row.

Comment: `.flat` just gives you an indexable 1D iterator, if you need some control over row vs column first, have a look at `.flatten` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) but keep in mind that calling that give you a new copy of the array. Instead of trying to copy IDL exactly, you're probably better off rewriting the logic of specific bits of IDL in efficient Python/numpy instead of trying to get as close as possible to the syntax and semantics of IDL.